# neighbor searching algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search, 3d, geometry, stl-format

I have a **STL** file that contains the coordinates `(x,y,z)` of 3 points  `(p0, p1, p2)` of a triangle. these triangle represent a **3D** surface `f(x,y,z)`. The **STL** file might have over a 1000 triangles to represent a complex geometry.

for my application, I need to know the neighboring triangles for each triangle entry from the stl file. meaning that for each triangle, i have to pick 3 pairs of points `pair1=(p0,p1), pair2=(p0,p2), pair3= (p1,p2)` and compare them with pair of points in other triangles in the set

what's the best and most efficient algorithm to achieve this purpose? can i use a hashtree, hashmap?

Answer (score 1):

change the mesh representation to **point table** and **triangle faces table**. **STL** demands that all triangles are joined in their vertexes so no cutting of edges which means neighboring triangle always share one complete edge.

```
double pnt[points][3];
int    tri[triangles][3];
```

The `pnt` should be list of all distinct points (index sort it to improve speed for high point count). The `tri` should contain 3 indexes of points used in triangle. Sort them (asc or desc) to improve match speed.

Now if any triangle `tri[i]`  shares the same edge like `tri[j]` then those two are neighboring triangles.

```
if ((tri[i][0]==tri[j][0])&&(tri[i][1]==tri[j][1])
  ||(tri[i][0]==tri[j][1])&&(tri[i][1]==tri[j][2])) triangles i,j are neighbors
```

Add all combinations ...

If you need just neighboring points then find all triangles containing that points and all the other points used in those triangles are neighbors

To load **STL** to such structure do this:

1. **clear `pnt[],tri[]` lists/tables**
2. **process each triangle of STL**
3. **for each point of triangle**

   look if it is in `pnt[]` if yes use its index for new `triangle`. if not add new `point` to `pnt` and use its index for new `triangle`. When all 3 points done add new `triangle` to `tri`.

**Improving `pnt[]` performance**

Add index sort for `pnt[]` sorted by any coordinate for example `x` and improve performance of checking if `point` is already present in `pnt`.

So while adding `(xi,yi,zi)` into `pnt[]` find index of point that have the biggest `x` which is `xi>=pnt[i0][0]` via **binary search** and then scan all points in `pnt` until `x` crosses `xi` so `xi<pnt[i1][0]` this way you do not need to check all points.

If this is too slow (usually if number of points is bigger then 40000) you can improve performance more by segment index sorting (dividing index sort into segment pages of finite size like 8192 points)

**Improving `tri[]` performance**

You can also sort the `tri[]` by `tri[i][0]` so you can use binary search similarly to `pnt[]`.

Comment: What do you think about my solution? 1- create a Triangle structure that contains three points with x,y,z coordinates. 2- make an array of triangles and update them by reading entries from the stl file. 3- use an unordered_multimap and a hash function to hash all points to a table. 4- for each triangle, hash its points P0,P1 and P2 and find the id of the other triangles that are hashed to same location in the tables. 5- the neighboring triangles are the ones that have two shared points in the table.

Comment: @Arash that is almost the same as my approach so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going with `hashmap` where *values* are `sets` (based on tree) of references to `Tringles`, *keys* are those pairs of `Points` (lets call these pairs simply `Sides`) and some hashing function that would take into accout the property that hash of `Side` (a,b) should be equal to hash of (b,a).

Some kind of algorithm:

1. Read 3 `Points` and create from them 3 `Sides` and `Triangle`.
2. Add all that to `hashmap`: `map[side[i]].insert(tringle)`
3. Repeat 1-2 until you read all the data

Now you have a map with filled data. About the complexity of filling: insertion into `hashmap` are *constant-time at average* (it also depends on the hash-function) and insertion complexity into a `set` is *logarithmic* so the complete complexity of filleng data is `O(n*logm)` where `n` is the number of `Sides` and `m` is average number of `Tringles` with the same `Side`.

Normally each `set` would contain around 4 `Triangles`: 1 + 3 side-neighbours, so `logm` is relatively small (comparing to `n`) and could be not taken into account (suppose it is a constant). These suggestions lead us to some kind of conclusion: best-case complexity for filling is `O(n)` (no collisions, no rehashing, etc) and worst is `O(n*logn)` (worst-case inserting of `n` `Sides` by `1` average case in map and by `logn` case inserting into one set meaning all `Tringles` share the same `Side`).

Now to get all side-neighbours for some `Triangle`:

1. Get all 3 `sets` for each `Side` of that `Triangle` (e.g. `set[i] = map[triangle.sides[i]]`.
2. Get intersection of those 3 `sets` (exclude `triangle` to get only its side-neighbours).
3. Done.

About complexity of getting side-neighbours: *linearly-depent* on the size of the `sets` and relatively small comparing to 'n' in normal case.

**Note:** To get not *side*-neighbours but *point*-neighbours (assuming neighbours are called any 2 `Triangles` with common `Point` not `Side`) simply fill `sets` with `Points` instead of `Sides`. The above assumptions about time-complexities hold exept for constants.